# Get all global attribute values within an Id, tbody, tr, title

Tags: javascript, dom

Using pure javascript

My code

```
<div id="all-items">
    <table>

      <tbody>

       <tr title="Text 1"></tr>
       <tr title="Text 2"></tr>
       <tr title="Text 3"></tr>

     </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

I know with jQuery I can use

```
$("#all-items table tbody tr").title
```

will return

```
"Text 1"
```

but jQuery isn't working with my front end framework I'm using for some reason. In addition, I want to return all the values of the title attributes on the page within table rows.

Comment: What front end framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using javascript only...

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('all-items').getElementsByTagName('tr')
var titles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
   titles.push(rows[i].getAttribute("title"));
}

console.log(titles);
```

```html
<div id="all-items">
    <table>

      <tbody>

       <tr title="Text 1"></tr>
       <tr title="Text 2"></tr>
       <tr title="Text 3"></tr>

     </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Posting an answer that you can run the code, is that only with JavaScript on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

The @WalksAway answer is fine.  If you would like to reuse your jQuery selector though, you might look at **querySelectorAll()** as well.

```js
var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#all-items table tbody tr"));
var titles = items.map(function(item) { return item.title; });
console.log(titles);
```

```html
<div id="all-items">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr title="Text 1"></tr>
      <tr title="Text 2"></tr>
      <tr title="Text 3"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```